# How to change magento theme in 1.9.3.2 and remove the old theme?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, theme, rwd-theme, magento-1.9.3.2

[image]

I uploaded Hallow theme for the first time in Magento ver. 1.9.3.2 but unfortunately I had lot of errors like images are not shown in browser etc.

Now I want to remove the previous theme and upload the new theme through Magento connect but at last step it doesn't clear the cache.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Did you checked Hallow theme tutorial and tried? Regarding remove old theme remove old theme folder from app/design/front-end/old_theme and skin/front-end/old_theme.

Comment: I see there are exceptions. Any idea what these exceptions are (you probably need to check your log). And have you tried flushing your cache?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do with magento connect just follow below steps

- upload all folders of theme in root directory.
- set theme package name and theme name at `admin->system->generel(from left side)->design.`
- set **theme package** name and set theme name in **default** field.

now, delete **cache** folder from `root directory->var folder`

now refresh homepage well. It will work

and if images still not showing then check **media** folder and its files permissions or folder permissions where images are coming.

i hope it will help !!